# Running bundle exec pod install is create an unnecessary change in the Gemfile for ruby

Tags: ios, ruby, gemfile.lock

I ran `ruby -v` on My system's root and the version I got is

`ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]`

I verified that my project is using same version by navigating to my project directory and running `ruby -v` again. I got-

`ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]`

However, anytime I do, `bundle exec pod install`, I get a change on my gemfile.lock file.

[image]

Any anyone help me with the issue.